# Does the main thread in java finish up before any processes it might create using Runtime class finish executing

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime.exec

I am using the Runtime class to execute a piece of installation of a software. However, its not working, meaning that, after I fire the job (which is created using the Runtime class), after sometime (which is very soon) the installation job just exits. I think the problem is that the main thread must be finishing up and thus killing the Process that is created using the Runtime class. Am I correct ? And what is the solution here ?

this is how I fire my job inside teh main class :

```
try
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        }                               
        catch(IOException e)    
        {   
            //add logging functionality
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Soon after this command, the main function finishes.

There is no problem with the Runtime command. It works .. I can even see it starting(the installation taht I am firing thru the code) and then it suddenly exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out the java.lang.Process class. You probably want something like this:

```
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        process.waitFor();
```

The subprocess may be receiving a SIGHUP and exiting.

EDIT:

In context, something like this, I would think:

```
    try
    {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        process.waitFor();
    }                               
    catch(IOException e)    
    {   
        //add logging functionality
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)    
    {   
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The process created is a *child* process for the main thread. If the main thread finishes, the process will be killed, similar to if you executed a command manually and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> or closed the window.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but I think to program quit's because you have a error in your code(logical) maybe a while loop that exits to soon,

try to look good at the code that the Runtime executes.

The process is probably in a deadlock. The solution is in the comments, with a sample.

Comment: hi, I am 100% certain that there is no problem in the code that is being started by runtime. I have tested it separately.

Comment: try this site: http://vyvaks.wordpress.com/2006/05/27/does-runtimeexec-hangs-in-java/

Comment: It is probably a deadlock of the process.